# How do I open a CSV File via VBA Script in a Powerpoint PPTM

Tags: vba, csv, adodb, powerpoint

I have a complicated Powerpoint Presentation that eventually gets exported as a bunch of single slides via ISpringPro

Because of the export process, the navigation links between the slides need to be managed so that individual exported slides can navigate to others.

I'm trying to write a VBA Script to allow a global find & replace of all Hyperlinks in the powerpoint.

My prototype version works fine where you type a single URL in an InputBox and a second url in a second Input Box to find and replace. But I'd like to just read all this info in from a 2 Column CSV file and have it look overall of them.

I'm now having trouble getting VBA to open the CSV file using the ADODB Connection. I think I might be missing a reference but VBA really isn't my strong suit.

I've pasted the code below. but it's blowing up on the `Set cn = New ADODB.Connection` saying that it doesn't know what that type is.

Am I missing some sort of assembly reference ?

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    Dim csvPath As String
    Dim csvFolder As String

    csvPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    csvFolder = StripFilename(csvPath)


    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim col As Integer

    strsql = "SELECT OLDURL,NEWURL FROM " & csvPath


    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, f As Integer

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    'On Error Resume Next
    cn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
        "Dbq=" & strFolder & ";" & _
        "Extensions=csv,tab,txt;"
    'On Error GoTo 0
    If cn.State <> adStateOpen Then Exit Sub
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    'On Error Resume Next
    rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    'On Error GoTo 0
    If rs.State <> adStateOpen Then
        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If


Dim iRet As Integer

    For f = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        iRet = MsgBox(rs.Fields(f).Name)
    Next f

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing



End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch that.

I needed to run power point as Administrator and then in the Macro Editor go to

Tools > References >

and add a reference to the latest Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects library.